# Passing a Global Variable, Why this wont work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, syntax

I am having a problem passing a varible from one function to another and I defined the variable OUTSIDE of a function so as far as I know, It Should be Global..

Here are the functions along with the RadioButtons that I pulled the value from.

```
<!-- Here is the Form Part -->
        <form method="post" action="#pizzatoppingtypes" name="pizzatoppings" id="pizzatoppingsform">

        <div id="main">
            <div class="example">
              <div>
                <input id="plainpizza" type="radio" name="pizzatoppings" value="0" checked="checked"><label style="color:black" for="plainpizza"><span><span></span></span>Plain Pizza</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="onepizza" type="radio" name="pizzatoppings" value="1"><label style="color:black" for="onepizza"><span><span></span></span>1 Topping</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="twopizza" type="radio" name="pizzatoppings" value="2"><label style="color:black" for="twopizza"><span><span></span></span>2 Toppings</label>
              </div>        
              <div>
                <input id="threepizza" type="radio" name="pizzatoppings" value="3"><label style="color:black" for="threepizza"><span><span></span></span>3 Toppings</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="fourpizza" type="radio" name="pizzatoppings" value="4"><label style="color:black" for="fourpizza"><span><span></span></span>4 Toppings</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="fivepizza" type="radio" name="pizzatoppings" value="5"><label style="color:black" for="fivepizza"><span><span></span></span>5 Toppings</label>
              </div>    
              <div>
                <input id="sixpizza" type="radio" name="pizzatoppings" value="15"><label style="color:black" for="sixpizza"><span><span></span></span>6 Or More Toppings</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="tacopizza" type="radio" name="pizzatoppings" value="8"><label style="color:black" for="tacopizza"><span><span></span></span>Taco Pizza</label>
              </div>              
            </div>


            <div class="one_third_last">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <input class="contact_button button" type="submit" name="submit" id="pizzatoppingsform" value="Next" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
<!--Form End-->

<!--Here is the JS-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRadioVal(form, name) {
    // get list of radio buttons with specified name
    var radios = form.elements[name];

    // loop through list of radio buttons
    for (var i=0, len=radios.length; i<len; i++) {
        if ( radios[i].checked ) { // radio checked?
            var vam = radios[i].value; // if so, hold its value in val
            break; // and break out of for loop
        }
    }
    return vam; // return value of checked radio or undefined if none checked
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var val; //Defined Here So That It Should Be Able To Be Used On Both Functions Below.
            <!--Figures Out How Many Toppings The Person Wants-->
            $('#pizzatoppingsform').submit(function( event ) {
                    val = getRadioVal(this, 'pizzatoppings');
                    alert(val); //Used Just To Verify The Value Is Being Stored.  
                    });

            <!--Limits How Many Check Boxes A Person Can Select Based On How Many Toppings They Selected. -->
            $("input[name='toppingtypes']").change(function () {
                var maxAllowed = Number(val); //If I Use An Actual Number Such As 2 Instead of This val Variable, This Function Works.
                var cnt = $("input[name='toppingtypes']:checked").length;
                if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
                    $(this).prop("checked", "");
                    alert('You can select a maximum of' + maxAllowed + ' Toppings');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Note: This last Function here where I have "var maxAllowed = Number(val);", When I insert a number instead for example 2, that function works. So as far as I know, the problem resides in the variable not being transferred over even though I declared it outside of a function.

Here Is my Git Hub Repository if you want to see more of the code.

https://github.com/dhierholzer/onlineordering

Thanks again.

Comment: Where is your js code?

Comment: by the way if your script tags are at the end of your html you don't need to use $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = getRadioVal(this, 'pizzatoppings');
```

by using `var` you're no longer referencing the global `val`--you're using a local with the same name.

Comment: okay, so i changed var val = getRadioVal(this, 'pizzatoppings'); to val = getRadioVal(this, 'pizzatoppings'); and still have no luck.. is that what you ment? just take out the var?

Comment: Yes, but you're also mixing jQuery with regular javascript. I'd put that code in a single `$(document).ready(...)` and scope `val` to within that. then bind using jquery `$('#pizzatoppingsform').submit()`.

Comment: so I combined the two and tried to use all jquery syntax as follows
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   var val;
   $('#pizzatoppingsform').submit(function( event ) {
     val = getRadioVal(this, 'pizzatoppings');
     alert(val);
     });
   $("input[name='toppingtypes']").change(function () {
    var maxAllowed = val;
    var cnt = $("input[name='toppingtypes']:checked").length;
    if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
     $(this).prop("checked", "");
     alert('You can select maximum ' + maxAllowed + ' Toppings');
    }
   });
  });
</script> 
Let me know, thanks

Comment: If that is too hard to read, I have updated my Git Hub To this code as well. Thanks again for your time and help.
https://github.com/dhierholzer/onlineordering